# How to send a php code inside a url to another page?

Tags: php, url, innerhtml

I need to send a php code inside the url, is there an option? On the function page I need CONTAINER html elements with php code because I have to create a new page.

```
<div id="CONTAINER">
<div id="one"><?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?></div>
<div id="two"><?php echo 'Hello!'; ?></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionSend()" >Send</button>
```

```
    function myFunctionSend() {
    var xhttp; 
    str = document.getElementById("CONTAINER").innerHTML;
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("CONTAINER").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("CONTAINER").innerHTML = document.getElementById("CONTAINER").innerHTML;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "page-function.php?CONTAINER=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to pass the PHP code instead of just the result? I mean, in the posted code, you're just echoing static strings, which doesn't make sense in any way. Just write the string directly in HTML instead. I would also recommend using POST instead of GET when you need to send data from the client to the server.

Comment: On the function page I have to create a new page with everything in Container html + php

Comment: Create a php-file that contains all the contents you want and load that file (with PHP's include/require) instead of passing the contents like that. If you pass the content (including PHP), you would need to use `eval()` to actually execute the PHP. Doing `eval()` on data that comes from the client (which an ajax request does), you're opening yourself up for _major_ security issues. Example: anyone could modify the payload and run what ever PHP code they want on your server. _Never_ trust data that comes from the client.

Comment: That makes sense, I absolutely agree. Is there an option to submit only innerHTML to the function page and then to put some php code into the div elements, and later create the php page. Maybe : https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php

Comment: Why can't you just have the HTML as is in a file and load that file? What is it you need to pass along to the new page? Will the HTML be different for each request?

Comment: I need to use div id one or div id two in the php code. After that I would create a page that has html and php, newfilename with newpagecontent

Comment: It may be better to switch html on the function page, then insert it into div and div two php code, then create a new page. Does the innerHTML option in php exist in the same way as javascript?